# lodash bind with javascript map in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

Right now I'm using `lodash partial` and the code works fine. However, I would like to use the `this` keyword in my map function. I need to change the following code to use `lodash bind`.

```
picksCount = 0;

gamesSelector(gamesAndPicks: {}): GameVM[] {
  const games = _.values<Game>(gamesAndPicks[0]).filter(game => game.weekNum === this.weekNum);
  const picks = _.values<Pick>(gamesAndPicks[1]).filter(pick => pick.weekNum === this.weekNum && pick.userId === this.userId);

  return games.map(_.partial(this.mapGameToGameVM, picks));
}

mapGameToGameVM(picks: Pick[], game: Game): GameVM {
  // want to use the this keyword in this function
  // ex this.picksCount 
  return { /*GameVM*/ };
}
```

I tried the following

```
  return games.map(_.bind(this.mapGameToGameVM, picks));
}

mapGameToGameVM(picks: Pick[], game: Game): GameVM {
  // want to use the this keyword in this function
  // ex this.picksCount 
  return { /*GameVM*/ };
}
```

But got a typescript error

```
Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 
'(value: Game, index: number, array: Game[]) => {}'.
Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature
'(value: Game, index: number, array: Game[]): {}'
```